# UI not showing changes, Universal Windows

Tags: c#, user-interface, async-await, refresh, uwp

OK to explain my problem,
It works like this:

```
    private void btnScan_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtCodigoBarras.Text = "Something";
    }
```

However, it doesn't work like this:

```
    private void btnScan_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        txtCodigoBarras.Text = "Something";
        ScanDefault();
    }
```

---

The scan default code is:

```
private void ScanDefault()
    {

        scanner.UseCustomOverlay = false;

        scanner.TopText = "Hold camera up to barcode";
        scanner.BottomText = "Camera";

        //Start scanning
        scanner.Scan().ContinueWith(t =>
        {
            if (t.Result != null)
            {
                HandleScanResult(t.Result);
            }

        });
    }
```

The scanner uses a grid that fills the screen, during this time I cannot change anything that it's not in that grid. The grid is running in another thread, when I cal the main thread controls and give them values, they accept the values, but visually there is no change

Comment: Please give more detail as to what you are expecting. It's kind of hard to tell from the example you gave

Comment: The scanner uses a grid that fills the screen, during this time I cannot change anything that it's not in that grid. The grid is running in another thread, when I cal the main thread controls and give them values, they accept the values, but visually there is no change.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that the `SynchronizationContext` changes in the ContinueWith callback. To avoid this, use `ConfigureAwait(true)`.

I think you should move to an `async` method like so:

```
private async void ScanDefault()
{
    scanner.UseCustomOverlay = false;

    scanner.TopText = "Hold camera up to barcode";
    scanner.BottomText = "Camera";

    //Start scanning
    var scanResult = await scanner.Scan().ConfigureAwait(true);
    HandleScanResult(scanResult);
}
```

1. Mark you method as `async`, allowing you to use `await`.
2. Change return type from `void` to `Task` (if it wasn't a `void`, you could return `Task<previousReturnType>`.
3. `await` you `scanner.Scan()` call, at this point the control will be returned to the called (btnScan_Click in this case)
4. Add `ConfigureAwait(true)` to return on the same `SynchronizationContext` as before the `await`.

Everything after your `await` will only get executed once the control returns after the `await`.

Comment: Your answer was good, sadly for me it's not the solution.
I can tell by the debug break points that the "txtCodigoBarras.Text" get the value I'm giving him, for some reason it just doesn't sow on the UI

The code you provide however made it faster

Comment: @CFG it doesn't work?

Comment: the problem still persists, I edited the previous answer while you were responding to something more usefull

Comment: I found a way around the problem, it's not a solution. since I use a new page on a new thread it erased all the changes I'm doing in the main page, so I store it in a public variable I use to make information travel throughout the app to return the variable I wanted once it was visible again. This is really bad practice, so if someone finds a actual solution it would be preferable. Thank you for your effort

Answer (score 0):

You can use ThreadPool threads instead use UI thread. For example ( function Scan() return string as I understand) :

```
private async void btnScan_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
txtCodigoBarras.Text = "Something";
var result = await Task.Run(() =>ScanDefault()).ConfigureAwait(false);
// working  here with variable result ...
}

private async Task<string> ScanDefault()
{

scanner.UseCustomOverlay = false;

scanner.TopText = "Hold camera up to barcode";
scanner.BottomText = "Camera";

//Start scanning
return scanner.Scan();
}
```

But remember that code in ScanDefault will working now in other Thread !